# How to bind the kendo dropdownlist to asp.net web api without ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a kendo dropdownlist. I am making an ajax call to my web api to bind that.
Dropdownlist:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ddlDepartment")
            .DataValueField("DeptId")
            .DataTextField("DeptName")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .AutoBind(false)
            )
```

Ajax Call to Web Api:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var ddl = $('#ddlDepartment').data("kendoDropDownList");
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8648/api/dropdown/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(data);
                    ddl.setDataSource(data);
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });
        })
```

But i want to bind it directly with the Api as similar as we bind it with normal action method in default mvc controller.
My Api Method:

```
// GET api/dropdown
        public IEnumerable<Department> Get()
        {
            List<Department> depart = _departmentTask.GetAll();
            return depart;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("products")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px" })
          .DataTextField("DeptName")
          .DataValueField("DeptId")
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Url("http://localhost:8648/api/dropdown/").Type(HttpVerbs.Get);
              }); 
          })
```

Api:

```
// GET api/dropdown
        public IEnumerable<Department> Get()
        {
            List<Department> depart = _departmentTask.GetAll();
            return depart;
        }
```

Comment: You might consider using `@Url.Action` for generating the datasource read url. That way you won't have any bad surprises after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your controller is called `dropdown` and your action is called `Get`, you can [bind the dropdown to a remote data source](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/remotedatasource.html):

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
 .Name("ddlDepartment")
 .DataValueField("DeptId")
 .DataTextField("DeptName")
 .SelectedIndex(0)
 .DataSource(source =>
  {
       source.Read(read =>
       {
           read.Action("Get", "dropdown");

       });
)
```

Please note that you might have to change your controller to return a `JsonResult`.

There is a behind-the-scene Ajax call, but Kendo handles that for you. You can also [bind events to the Ajax call as depicted in the online demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/events.html).